# QtQuick.Controls Shortcut context overlap between windows

Tags: qt, qml

I'm working on a QtQuickControls app, and I've noticed some difficult behaviour regarding Shortcut contexts. When using QtQuick.Controls 2.0, Window-specific Shortcuts appear to be overriding each other. My application is entirely key-driven, and consists of multiple Pages/Popups (industrial control panel). I decided on Shortcuts due to their simplicity and lack of focus management. I know that my implementation is legal, since it works with QtQuick.Controls 2.2. A rough outline of the implementation is below.

```
ApplicationWindow{
    id: mainWindow

    Shortcut{
        objectName: "menuButton"
        context: Qt.WindowShortcut
        sequence: "z"
        onActivated: {
            mainMenu.open()
        }
    }    
}

Popup{
    id: mainMenu
    anchors.fill: parent
    Rectangle{
        id: rectangle
        color: "#ffffff"
    }

    Shortcut{
        id: changeColor
        context: Qt.WindowShortcut
        sequence: "z"
        onActivated: {
            rectanlge.color = "steelblue"
        }
    }
}
```

It's a rough implementation, but I've noticed that two Shortcuts with the same sequence will cancel each other out after the first press of that sequence, even if their context are two mutually exclusive windows. Is this a bug? Are there any workarounds? This is working in Qt 5.9.0 with QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.  Shortcut has an `enabled` property that can be toggled depending on when Popups are visible.  See here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43644761/qml-keyboard-shortcuts-are-interfering-with-key-onpressed-events)